# Debian 8 Jessie and PHP > 7.2

Tags: php, debian

I recently restored my personal test server with a completely fresh install of Debian 8.

The Service Provider where I purchased the Virtual Server, has only the Debian 8 option. So there is currently no possibility to upgrade to stretch or buster (9 and 10).

I need to install at least `PHP 7.2` on my server to meet the requirements for the project and I'm having a hard time accomplishing that. As [www.dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org) seems to be discontinued I am wondering what package source I should add for `PHP 7.2`. All I found googling around was when dotdeb was still providing `7.2` packages.

My `sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://debian.mirror.serverloft.de/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.mirror.serverloft.de/debian-security/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

but when I do

```
apt-get uptate
apt-get install php 7.2
```

I get

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
```

Maybe there is no such option anymore and I have to change the provider to get a higher Debian version?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's preventing you from updating the virtual server to a new debian version? If you can modify the sources list you could also update the debian source definition

Comment: the thing is i talked with the service provider and he told me that their virtual software wouldnt allow that for some reason (im guessing some of the libs are share(?)). Im not sure if he knew what he was talking about tho ;). He just said after the restart the instance would be damaged, so im not sure if its worth the time to invest

Comment: Dist-upgrade can break everything, and how to recover then? Safe upgrade requires buying new server and migrating all services one by one, making sure they all work. That is long work, and why if we can solve problem faster. Like, for instance, OpenSSL bastards didn't blink an eye removing exported library symbols. Unthinkable, compared to Win32 incrementally growing API! https://github.com/AdaCore/aws/issues/24 I wondered how didn't their code broke, only to find they wrote #define in their stupid C, and all other languages didn't autodiscover that. Linux culture leaves much to desire.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the php 7.2 or later in debian jessie. But you need to follow some steps for getting this. The main reason is debian platform has been stopped the sury package service for jessie. Please check this link https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/
Now you know, it's not have the jessie support.

Okay Now we start the process of php 7.2 installation

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main`.
   It helps to get the stretch repos for the supporting dependencies of php 7.2
2. `$ sudo apt update`
3. `$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list`.

   then add deb `https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch  main`. this is also a stretch repo
4. `$ sudo apt update`
5. Now the php needs the updation of libncurses5 >= 6
   check the current available version of libncurses5

   `$ sudo apt search libncurses5` //it shows you the libncurses5 as 6.0

   `$ sudo apt install  libncurses5`
6. `$ sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-readline php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm`
7. `$ sudo apt install php7.2-common php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-imagick php7.2-dev php7.2-imap php7.2-mbstring php7.2-opcache php7.2-soap php7.2-zip php7.2-intl -y`
8. check unix socket is found in `/var/run/php`

Now you found `php7.2-fpm.sock` in this directory

9. Last step. just start the php service: `$ sudo service php7.2-fpm start`
   Now you check the status and version of php `$ sudo service php7.2-fpm status` && `$ php -v`

Hurray. you got the newest version of php. Thanks a lot

Note: Don't forget to stop the previous service for php in your machine

Answer (score -2):

I've got PHP 8.0 from this all-in-one bundle: https://bitnami.com/stack/lapp/installer

It does not depend on Linux distro

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.